# Select highest value for each foreign key using time interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database of measurements for different locations that is taken every 1 hour.

```
ID | LOCATION_ID | CMS | DATE
6  | C           | 7   | 2014-11-27 12:00:00
5  | B           | 3   | 2014-11-27 12:00:00
4  | A           | 19  | 2014-11-27 12:00:00
3  | C           | 9   | 2014-11-27 11:00:00
2  | B           | 8   | 2014-11-27 11:00:00
1  | A           | 11  | 2014-11-27 11:00:00
```

I need to select the highest `cms` for each unique location, within the last 3 hours. For example;

```
ID | LOCATION_ID | CMS | DATE
3  | C           | 9   | 2014-11-27 11:00:00
2  | B           | 8   | 2014-11-27 11:00:00
4  | A           | 19  | 2014-11-27 12:00:00
```

I am using the below MySQL to return the max, but I am missing the final piece. What do I need to complete the statement?

```
SELECT MAX(cms) as value_of_rain 
FROM `rainfall`
WHERE `date` >= SUBDATE( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 3 HOUR )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the grouping statement using `GROUP BY` like

```
SELECT MAX(cms) as value_of_rain 
FROM `rainfall`
WHERE `date` >= SUBDATE( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 10 MINUTE )
GROUP BY LOCATION_ID
```

Comment: although the result's kind of meaningless if the location_id is missing from the select